# android app GCMRegistrar.checkDevice in the new API

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Please could any body here tell me how to use GCMRegistrar.checkDevice in the new API or what could replace it please?

Comment: `checkDevice` method checks if the device has the proper dependencies installed. As stated [here](http://www.bdtool.net/third/android-doc/web-docs/guide/google/gcm/client-javadoc/com/google/android/gcm/GCMRegistrar.html#checkDevice(Context)), this method should be called when the application starts to verify that the device supports GCM. Here are [examples](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar) on how to use it.

Comment: I know but this API is deprecated so in new API what is the substitute for it

Answer (score 0):

In the new API you should check for the existence of Play Services.

The [GCM quickstart](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart/MainActivity.java#L71) has an example of it.